# Divisibility problem: show $(x-z)\mid xy+zw \implies (x-z)\mid xw+yz$

Tags: number-theory, divisibility

I'm stuck at this homework problem can someone help me out?  Much appreciated!

$$(x-z)\mid xy+zw \implies (x-z)\mid xw+yz$$
Thanks again!

Comment: Can you share what you've done so we can better assist?

Answer (score 8):

It's actually pretty simple:

$$(xy+wz)-(xw+yz)=x(-w+y)-z(-w+y)=(x-z)(-w+y)$$

Answer (score 7):

$\begin{eqnarray}\rm {\bf Hint}\ \ mod\ x\!-\!z\!:\,\ \color{#C00}x\equiv \color{#0A0}z\ &\Rightarrow&\rm\, \ \ \ \ \ \  \color{#C00}x\,y+\color{#0A0}z\,w\\
&&\rm\ \equiv\, \color{#0A0}z\,y + \color{#C00}x\,w\end{eqnarray}$

**Remark** $\ $ Notice how much simpler it is using congruences (*equational* reasoning) vs. divisibility (*relational* relasoning). Using congruences the proof is obvious: simply replace equals by equals. This simplification works quite generally. It allows us to convert less familiar *relational* statements to equivalent *equational* statements - where we can employ our well-practiced manipulation of *equations* (viewing congruences as generalized equations).

Comment: Coloring the fonts must be very difficult.? I like the colored parts ;).

+1 for the coloring.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Expand the polynomial $(x-z)(y-w)$.